# The Three Subjects

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So there are three things that I don't get at all so I would appreciate if someone could dumb it down for me. Completely dumb it down that is since I've found explanations on the internet that simply don't cut it down for me. Those are: Binary relation, equivalence relation and class equivalence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

A *binary* [relation](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(mathematics)) is a "connection" (or correspondence) between two collections (i.e. *sets*) or lists of objects.

> "___ is father of :::"

is a binary relation between the set of *men* (because only males con be fathers) and the set of *humans* (because of sons and daughters).

If John is the father of Mary, we say that John and Mary are "related" by the above relation.

Relations have properties :

> [reflexivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation) : a relation is *reflexive* when a thing is related to itself. The relation "father of" is **not** reflexive, becuase no man is father of itself.
>
> [symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation) : a relation is *symmetric* when if the thing $a$ is related to $b$, then also $b$ is related to $a$. The relation "father of" is **not** symmetric, becuase if John is the father of Mary, obviously Mary is not the father of John.
>
> [transitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) : again, the relation "father of" is **not** transitive.

---

Consider now the *arithmetical* relation "less or equal" : $\le$. As you can easily verify, it is reflexive and transitive, but not symmetric.

An [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) is a relation that is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

An example is :

> "___ has the same birthday as :::"

between humans.

---

The [equivalence class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) of an equivalnce relation is the grouping into a single class of all elements that are related to one another by the rleation.

Thus, considering the relation : "___ has the same birthday as :::" and the fact that I was born in December 2, 1959, all humans born in the same day will belong with me to the equivalence class : "humans born in December 2, 1959".